# How do I run downloaded project of laravel from cloud9 on localhost server?

Tags: php, laravel-5, wamp, git-bash, cloud9

I have made a project on cloud 9  using laravel.

Downloaded it.

Extracted in my project directory wamp/www/laravel.

I have been giving the following command on gitbash.

> cd e:/wamp/www/laravel

then

> php artisan serve

Then going to localhost:8000 in my browser,following error occurs

```
    PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
```

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'yash2code'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Have you set up your .env file with your database credentials?

Comment: @aynber yes it is set  
`APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:MsCoqavEYxSyrQuhAXbpYdxEMTnI2o8twQX6gOf47yM=
APP_URL=http://localhost
 

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=c9
DB_USERNAME=yash2code
DB_PASSWORD=


CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync


REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379


MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
`

Comment: You didn't enter your DB_PASSWORD. Your database doesn't have an account set up for 'yash2code'@'localhost' with no password listed, so you'll need to enter the correct credentials.

Comment: @aynber still not working.Getting same error.